# Replacing all instances of string containing hyphen

Tags: bash, string, tr

Running the following command:

```
echo "hello-world" | tr "hello-world" "Hello World"
```

Returns `Heddd-ddddd`. I want it to return `Hello World`. I believe this is because `tr` is interpreting the `SET1` argument as a range (from the `tr` manpage):

```
CHAR1-CHAR2
    all characters from CHAR1 to CHAR2 in ascending order
```

I have also tried:

```
echo ${"hello-world//hello-world/Hello World"}
```

Which returns:

```
bash: ${"hello-world//hello-world/Hello World"}: bad substitution
```

What is the preferred way to do this (translate all instances of a string to a different string)? Either with `tr` or another program.

Comment: put the hyphen at the end: `echo 'hello-world' | tr 'hw-' 'HW '`

Comment: @mosvy Thanks. This was just a simple example - what should I do when I have a more complex string with other instances of `h/w/-` that I don't want to affect? I've update the title to better reflect the actual problem - `tr` was just one approach I have tried.

Comment: `tr` is for mapping one-to-one between sets of *characters* - for *string* replacements, you should use something like `sed`

Comment: ... your shell parameter expansion approach would also work, provided your original string is inside a variable e.g. `str="hello-world" ; echo "${str/hello-world/Hello World}"` - it won't work on string literals AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Just we need to escape the `-`

```
echo "hello-world" | tr "hello\-world" "Hello World"
```

Luckily we don't have trailing `h` or `w` in the context to give a wired result. So, its better to replace the first char of each string to upper case.

Using `sed`

```
echo "hello-world" | sed 's/-/ /g;s/\<./\U&/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

- convert the hyphens with `tr`
- convert the first letter in each word to upper case (and print the rest of each word `($i,2)` without any conversion) with `awk`

  ```
  $ echo 'hello-world-peace' | tr '-' ' ' | \
   awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2) }} {print}'
  Hello World Peace
  ```

You can also use `awk` for the whole task,

- convert the hyphens with `gsub`
- convert the first letter in each word to upper case with `toupper`
- and print the rest of each word `($i,2)` without any conversion

  ```
  echo 'hello-world-peace' | \
   awk '{gsub("-"," "); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) \
   { $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2) }} {print}'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` would work:

```
echo "hello-world" |sed -E -n 's/.(.*)-.(.*)/H\1 W\2/p'
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```